# Facebook like working then not again

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Ok I have checked all the other posts that are similar to this but none of them are truely the same.

I have a like button on my website. The page is created dynamically via a perameter passed to the page called "page"

find here;

http://dev.crosbylakeside.co.uk/watersports/index.php?page=watersports

Now on the home page of this section the like button works great.  However it does not work on any other section at all!!

The strange thing is its essentially the same page.  If you check my source code header info its always right. The facebook og data is also dynamic to simulate page changes and is working fine.

If you go to the dev bugs page and put in the url of my site it all checks out ok.

I have tried everything but I cant seem to get it to go.

Please help thanks

Comment: Works fine for me on the sub page you mentioned (FF 13.0.1/Win7).

Comment: What does [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) say for the pages that don't work, are there any errors?

Comment: Works fine on my system (Chrome 19). Try deleting the cache for the page.

Comment: Ok Ive cleared my cache.  Even tried it in a new broswer and still nothing.  The home page works fine but If i click on any other page and try the same thing. Nothing.  It doesnt even appear on my FB for any other page other than the watersports home page which works fine.

Comment: The facebook debug tool has nothing to say :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like was a caching issue